# Rails: invalid object triggers errors but still gets saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a simple model:

score.rb

```
validates :dx1, presence: true
```

dx1 is one of its attributes and I am running a simple validation on it being present.

Here is the controller.

score_controller.rb

```
def update
 @patient =  Patient.find(@score.patient_id)
  respond_to do |format|
     if @score.update(score_params)
       format.html {  redirect_to edit_score_path(@score), notice: 'Score was successfully updated.' }
       format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @score }
     else
       format.html { render :edit, :patient => @patient, notice: @score.errors.full_messages.to_sentence }
      format.json { render json: @score.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
   end
 end
```

The behaviour is strange,

If I try to submit with dx1 blank, the error gets called, but it is still saved in the database with dx1 blank. Whatsmore, if I run this is the console,  the errors are logged in "errors" and the object returns false to valid? and yet it still gets saved.

Why is this?

Comment: Just to be sure, could you provide any additional info? The request's logs, any relevant callbacks from the model. Is the dx1 field included in the `score_params`? Are you running your server in development mode? (just to be certain that the validation actually applies there as well as it does in the console).

Comment: Have you restarted your server and console, and spring in case you use it?